# ¿ Por qué cuando hago una petición POST con fetch a mi API de flask, sigue ejecutando aún cuando ya envió los resultados?

Tags: javascript, api, flask, fetch

Soy nuevo en la realización de una API con flask.

A partir del siguiente código hago una petición POST con fetch

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',

  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "Punto_inicial": [-74.092389, 4.636756 ],
    "Punto_final":[-74.078618, 4.645129]
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => plot(data.distancia_x,data.elevacion))
```

La petición POST está configurada así:

```
@app.route('/products',methods=['POST'])
def addProduct():

    profile = Perfil(request.json["Punto_inicial"],request.json["Punto_final"])
    profile.datos_perfil()
    return jsonify(profile.profile_json)
```

Cuando le doy un console.log a los datos que trae, confirmo que si son correctos, sin embargo, no entiendo porque la petición se sigue ejecutando. ¿La petición no deberia finalizar cuando ya se obtienen los datos que retorna el servidor?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la parte de *se sigue ejecutando*? ¿Cómo lo sabes? ¿Se repite la llamada? Si ese fuera el caso, ¿podrías mostrar cómo realizas la petición? Y no me refiero al código de `fetch`, sino a cómo llamas o ejecutas dicho código. Saludos